# Merge array of objects by object key

Tags: javascript

[image]

Given the screenshot above I would like to merge this array by the "hand" attribute, so that the final result would be

```
[{hand: "KdAhAsKs", checkPct: 28, betPct: 72},{hand: "KcAhAsKs", checkPct: 28, betPct: 72}]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate the common property in an object corresponding to each unique `hand` and then take out all values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const data = [{hand: "KdAhAsKs", checkPct: 28}, {hand: "KdAhAsKs", betPct: 72},{hand: "KcAhAsKs", checkPct: 28}, { hand: "KcAhAsKs", betPct: 72}],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{hand, ...rest}) => {
      r[hand] = r[hand] || {hand};
      r[hand] = {...r[hand], ...rest};
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Hope this helps.

```js
const data = [{hand: "KdAhAsKs", checkPct: 28}, {hand: "KdAhAsKs", betPct: 72},{hand: "KcAhAsKs", checkPct: 28}, { hand: "KcAhAsKs", betPct: 72}];

const combine = (data) =>

    data.reduce((acc, val) => {

        const i = acc.findIndex(o => o.hand === val.hand);

        if (i !== -1) {

            acc[i] = { ...acc[i], ...val };

            return acc;
        }

        else return acc.concat(val);
    }, []);

console.log(combine(data));
```