# Group by similar data but keep keys and values javascript

Tags: javascript, json

During work I have problem with this task, here is my data :

```
var order = [
      {area: "RFCC",ru: "R401",tot: 3,unit: "OFFSITE"},
      {area: "RFCC",ru: "R401",tot: 1,unit: "RCU"}];
```

I want the result should be like this :

```
var order = [
    {area:["RFCC","RFCC"],ru:["R401","R401"],tot:[4],unit:["OFFSITE","RCU"]}]
```

Anyone know solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need final result to be an array with only one object in it rather than just  a single object and no array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498801/how-to-merge-two-object-values-by-keys  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224923/merge-array-of-objects-by-object-key

Comment: @charlietfl because I want to display data chart with single object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array#reduce()` to achieve this, by the following:

```js
var order = [
      {area: "RFCC",ru: "R401",tot: 3,unit: "OFFSITE"},
      {area: "RFCC",ru: "R401",tot: 1,unit: "RCU"}
];

var result = order.reduce((result, item) => {
  
  const { area, ru, tot, unit } = result[0]
   
  area.push( item.area );
  ru.push( item.ru );
  unit.push( item.unit );
  tot[0] = parseInt(tot[0]) + parseInt(item.tot);
  
  return result

}, [{ area : [], ru : [], tot: [ 0 ], unit : [] }])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "for..of" to loop through the array objects

```js
var order = [
      {area: "RFCC",ru: "R401",tot: 3,unit: "OFFSITE"},
      {area: "RFCC",ru: "R401",tot: 1,unit: "RCU"}
];
  
var result = {}

for(let obj of order) {
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    
    typeof value == "string" && (
      result[key] = result[key] ? result[key].concat(value) : [value]
    )
    
    typeof value == "number" && (
      result[key] = result[key] ? [result[key][0] + value] : [value]
    )
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You’re Welcome!! As these two answers follow different approach. Pls do spend some time understanding both of these as this will help you in future problems. Also in case of any issue do let us know.